# how to change "IHtmlString" to "MvcHtmlString"?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I'm writing 2 helper method to extend a implementation where I'm using "IHtmlString", how I can convert this to one method by using "MvcHtmlString"? Help...

```
public static IHtmlString ExceptionValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        const string template = "<div class=\"ui-widget\"><div class=\"ui-state-error ui-corner-all\" style=\"padding:0 .7em\"><div>" +
                                "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-alert\" style=\"float: left; margin-right: .3em;\"></span>" +
                                "<strong>Validation Exceptions:</strong></div><div style=\"margin-top: 5px;\"> " + 
                                "<ul style=\"font-weight: normal;\">{0}</ul></div></div></div>";

        StringBuilder exceptionList = new StringBuilder();

        // Iterate through the exceptions
        foreach (var error in helper.ViewData.ModelState.SelectMany(modelState => modelState.Value.Errors))
        {
            exceptionList.Append(string.Format("<li>{0}</li>", error.ErrorMessage));
        }

        return exceptionList.Length.Equals(0) ? string.Format("").Raw() : string.Format(template, exceptionList).Raw();

    }

    public static IHtmlString Raw(this string value)
    {
        return new HtmlString(value);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem - are you wanting to return a concrete MvcHtmlString instance instead of the abstract IHtmlString interface? Why not just return an MvcHtmlString instance directly?

Comment: how to concate both "template" and "exceptionList" to return an MvcHtmlString in my above case?

Answer (score 1):

Though I'd expect the `StringBuilder.ToString()` method to be implicitly called by `string.Format()`, if that is not happening, explicitly call the `ToString()` method like this:

```cs
string.Format(template, exceptionList.ToString())
```

Also, your method is declared to return an `IHtmlString`.  If you change the signature to use `MvcHtmlString`, that will tell the compiler your desired return type.  At this point, it is just a matter of ensuring the return value matches the updated declaration:

```cs
return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(template, exceptionList.ToString()));
```